# change the color of button in smart table on condition

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I want to change the color of a button on a condition: on clicking the "Add" button, the modal window appears, if comments are added to text area I want to change the color of the button. After clicking the submit button a rest call will be fired. Based on success or failure response I want to change my button color.

Controller Code

```
$scope.colorChange = false;
if(response.resp == 'success'){
    $scope.colorChange = true;
}
```

..
now when "colorChange" becomes true all rows "Add" button color changing. I want the admin commented button row color to change. I used ng-class
`ng-class="{'selected':colorChange == true}"`, but it is not working, please help me.

```
 .selected {
            background-color: #A52A2A;
            color: #FFFFFF;
           }
```

..

```
<table st-table="displayedCollection" st-safe-src="rowCollection" class="st-table table table-custom">
          <thead>
          <tr class="st-filters">
            <th colspan="5" style="padding-right: 30px">
              <input st-search placeholder="Table search" class="input-sm form-control" type="search"/>
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <th st-sort="firstName" class="sorting">FirstName</th>
            <th st-sort="lastName" class="sorting">Last Name</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr st-select-row="row"   st-select-mode="multiple" ng-repeat="row in displayedCollection">
          <td >{{row.firstName}}</td>
            <td>{{row.lastName}}</td>
           <td>
              <button class="btn btn-primary mb-8" ng-click="addminComment($event,row)" ng-class="{'selected':colorChange == true}"  data-options="splash-2 splash-ef-12">Add</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
          <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="5" class="text-center">
              <div st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="itemsByPage" st-displayed-pages="7"></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          </tfoot>
        </table>
```

Comment: that css rule selector is not specific enough

Comment: thanks for your reply, I used that button in ng-repeat  how to apply specific css rule.

Comment: would be better to change css. Add more nesting to selector to apply `.selected` class. For example .table .some-row .selected { ...

Comment: try it with `.btn.btn-primary.selected`. Inspect live html in browser dev tools to see ranking order of all style rules for any element